# IntelliJ 14 Java project not aware of Gradle dependancy

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have an  IntelliJ idea project which has a number of dependencies in `build.gradle`.

However just recently after adding dependencies to `buid.gradle`, IntelliJ doesn't seem to be aware of them (despite Gradle building and running the applicaition fine).

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url * } // Company's proxy  maven repository
}

dependencies {
    compile("wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.2")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.0-milestone-4'
    distributionUrl = * // Company gradle distrubution URL
}

apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "main.HelloWorld"
```

But when I use a class that is dependant, for example: [`javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader`](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/apis/wsdl4j/javax/wsdl/xml/WSDLReader.html), IntelliJ looks like this

[image]

Despite it compiling and running fine.

```
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build
:run
Hello, World

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

How do I make IntelliJ aware of the classes?

Comment: Did you import it as a gradle project?

Comment: Originally, I went `New->Project->Gradle`, I selected the *Create Directories for empty content roots automatically* but I left *Auto Import* unchecked. Then I filled in the name and clicked finish.

Comment: Open up preferences, search for gradle.  Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle and select the checkbox Use auto-import.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself:

Under the toolbar I went `View->Toolbars->Gradle`. Then a sub window opened on the right. I then clicked on the refresh button, shown here:

[image: refresh]

And after a few moments is was all good!